# Android web socket; cant receive more than 4*1024 character

Tags: android, websocket

I have downloaded websocket from below link :-
**https://github.com/elabs/mobile-websocket-example**

In **android websocket** I can receive only maximum 4096 = 4*1024 character, if sever send data more than 4*1024 character, then i cant able to receive message.

**How can i increase receive message limit in android?**

4*1024; is this limit set in web socket client or android server? or any packet limit in android?

Comment: I'm using this library for sockets on android and I don't have such issues: https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java

Answer (score -1):

[build.gradle](https://github.com/elabs/mobile-websocket-example/blob/master/android/WebsocketExampleClientProject/WebsocketExampleClient/build.gradle) of [mobile-websocket-example](https://github.com/elabs/mobile-websocket-example) says it uses [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket). Probably, the limitation is coming from the implementation of [WebSocketClient](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/client/WebSocketClient.java). Start reading from `WebSocketClient.run()`. A fixed-size buffer is allocated and it seems `WebSocketImpl.decodeFrames(ByteBuffer)` assumes that frame sizes do not exceed the buffer size.

[Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) is popular but I doubt its quality. Experienced programmers can guess quality to some extent only by reading source codes without executing the binary.